# brush extents not working as expected

Tags: d3.js

For some reason my chart is not getting brushed as I was hoping it would. The domain of brush.extent() seems to be working, but the bars are all flying off the page. Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

```
function doBrush() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.select("rect").attr("x",  function(d) { return x(d.from); });
    focus.select("rect").attr("width",  function(d) {return x(d.to) - x(d.from);});
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

https://jsbin.com/layecehidu/edit?js,console,output

Comment: I'm not following this question... your question has `selectAll`, however, your JSBin has `select`. If you change it to `selectAll`, it will work: https://jsbin.com/xecegipepe/1/edit?js,output

Comment: you are right. I didn't notice my own typo. If you post this as an answer I will be more than happy to award you the bounty. Thanks!

Comment: Keep your points: write yourself an answer and accept it after 2 days. That way, you can receive your bounty back.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado For SE in general this is not true: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work. You cannot receive your own bounty back. Unless SO has a different ruleset the bounty can only be awarded to other users.

Comment: @altocumulus You are right: the link says that this was possible, but it was removed. Thus, @ konrad, I'm afraid your lost your RP because of a typo!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado A typical use case of that would be: 1) Award a 500 rep bounty. 2) Benefit from the well-researched, canonical answer. 3) Accept your own, inferior answer, and 4) Reclaim your rep points.

Comment: Well, I am not getting it back, so why not just hand them to the man who spotted my typo? If you post that link to jsBin as an answer I will hand it over...you have helped me here before. I am more than grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're using `select` where you should use `selectAll` instead.

The obvious difference between `select` and `selectAll`, as the very name of the methods imply, is that `select`...

> selects the first descendant element that matches the specified selector string.

... while `selectAll`:

> Selects all elements that match the specified selector string.

That's not the only difference, though. Grouping and data propagation are less well known differences. Look at this table:

| Method | select() | selectAll() |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Selection | selects the first element that matches the selector string | selects all elements that match the selector string |
| Grouping | Does not affect grouping | Affects grouping |
| Data propagation | Propagates data | Doesn't propagate data |

That being said, your code should be:

```
function doBrush() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.selectAll("rect").attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.from);
    })
    focus.selectAll("rect").attr("width", function(d) {
        return x(d.to) - x(d.from);
    });
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

Here is the code with that change only:

```js
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

var data=[
 {"category": "Task 1", "from": "1-Jan-17", "to": "15-Jan-17", "progress":100, "synched": ["5-Jan-17", "7-Jan-17"]},
 {"category": "Task 2", "from": "13-Jan-17", "to": "1-Feb-17", "progress":60, "synched": ["15-Jan-17"]},
 {"category": "Task 1", "from": "1-Feb-17", "to": "11-Mar-17", "progress":90, "synched": ["2-Feb-17", "4-Feb-17"]}
]

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.from = parseDate(d.from);
    d.to = parseDate(d.to);
});

var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    margin2 = {top: 330, right: 10, bottom: 30, left: 100},
    width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    height2 = 400 - margin2.top - margin2.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var x2 = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height], 0.2);
var y2 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, height2], 0.2);

y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.category; }));
x.domain([d3.min(data,function(d){return d.from;}), d3.max(data,function(d){return d.to;})]);
x2.domain(x.domain());
y2.domain(y.domain());

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(15)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d%b"));

var xAxis2 = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x2)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(15)
    .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%d%b"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
    .x(x2)
    .on("brush", doBrush);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("defs")
    .append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var focus = svg.append("g")
var context = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + margin2.top + ")");

var focusRectangleGroups = focus.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

focusRectangleGroups.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.category); })
    .attr("height", y.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.from); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.to) - x(d.from); });

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", width-margin.right)
    .attr("dx", ".71em")
    .attr("dy", "-0.2em")
    .text("Date");

focus.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var contextRectangleGroups = context.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("g");

contextRectangleGroups.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y2(d.category); })
    .attr("height", y2.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x2(d.from); })
    .attr("width", function(d) { return x2(d.to) - x2(d.from); })
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)");

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height2 + ")")
    .call(xAxis2);

context.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x brush")
    .call(brush)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .attr("y", -6)
    .attr("height", height2 + 7);

function doBrush() {
    x.domain(brush.empty() ? x2.domain() : brush.extent());
    focus.selectAll("rect").attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.from); })
    focus.selectAll("rect").attr("width", function(d) { return x(d.to) - x(d.from); });
    focus.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

```css
.pending {
        fill: #e74c3c;
    }

    .bar {
        fill: #2ecc71;
    }

/*     .bar:hover, .pending:hover {
      fill: #3498db;
    } */

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .legend {
        padding: 5px;
        font: 16px sans-serif;
        background: yellow;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
    }

    .tooltip {
        background: #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999999;
        color: #333;
        font-size: 12px;
        left: 130px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 95px;
        z-index: 10;
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }
.axis,
.frame {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

    .axis path {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .axis text {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: grey;
        stroke-width: 1;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

.brush .extent {
    stroke: #fff;
    fill-opacity: .125;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```