# d3.js. How to update nested nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zeleniy/xj71evmv/). I expect that after second step when i update table rows with new data set it will show 3 and 4. But it still show 1 and 2. Why? Why nested elements still keep old data set? How to fix it? How to update nested tags?

```
const data1 = [1, 2];

const table = d3.select('body')
  .append('table')
  .append('tbody');

table
  .selectAll('tr')
  .data(data1)
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .append('td')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

const data2 = [3, 4];

table
  .selectAll('tr')
  .data(data2)
  .selectAll('td')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

Comment: I found that if on second step replace `.selectAll('td')` with `.select('td')` it works fine, but why?

Comment: This table I made may help you to understand the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44897592/5768908

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment question, this is a subselection [select](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_select).  From the docs:

> Unlike selection.selectAll, selection.select does not affect grouping: it preserves the existing group structure and indexes, and propagates data (if any) to selected children. Grouping plays an important role in the data join. See Nested Selections and How Selections Work for more on this topic.

The important part here is **propagates data to selected children**.